# Combining .Any and EF.Functions.Like

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

Combining `EF.Functions.Like` and `.Any` seems to result in an untranslatable expression. Is there a way to perform the following query?

```
var searchTerms = new[] { "%red%", "%blue%", /* unknown number of terms here */ };

var widgets = await Widgets
    .Where(w => searchTerms.Any(term => EF.Functions.Like(w.Name, term)))
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

I had hoped the above would translate into the equivalent SQL:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Widgets
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT  1
    FROM    @tbl_terms
    WHERE   [Name] LIKE term
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a way. Thanks to one @BladeWise [on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10834#issuecomment-362221156) (oh, and here, apparently ), I've got a fancy new `WhereAny` extension method.

```
internal static class QueryBuilderHelpers
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAny<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, params Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] predicates)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        return queryable.Where(
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                predicates.Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, bool>>, Expression>(
#pragma warning disable CS8625 // Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.
                    default,
#pragma warning restore CS8625 // Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.
                    (current, predicate) =>
                    {
                        var visitor = new ParameterSubstitutionVisitor(predicate.Parameters[0], parameter);
                        return current != default
                            ? Expression.OrElse(current, visitor.Visit(predicate.Body))
                            : visitor.Visit(predicate.Body);
                    }),
                parameter));
    }

    class ParameterSubstitutionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        readonly ParameterExpression _destination;
        readonly ParameterExpression _source;

        public ParameterSubstitutionVisitor(ParameterExpression source, ParameterExpression destination)
        {
            _source = source;
            _destination = destination;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) => ReferenceEquals(node, _source) ? _destination : base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```